# Javascript Array from PHP Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**I have an Array as bellow**

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Homeslider' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => null,
            'display_photo' => '1402379775bdaebd329b69.jpg',
            'order_no' => null,
            'created' => '2014-06-10 05:56:15',
            'modified' => '2014-06-10 05:56:15'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Homeslider' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'title' => null,
            'display_photo' => '1402379784a426fe476711.jpg',
            'order_no' => null,
            'created' => '2014-06-10 05:56:24',
            'modified' => '2014-06-10 05:56:24'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Homeslider' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'title' => null,
            'display_photo' => '1402379793cb81f1a5bbf9.jpg',
            'order_no' => null,
            'created' => '2014-06-10 05:56:33',
            'modified' => '2014-06-10 05:56:33'
        )
    )
)
```

What i am trying to achieve

```
["img/default/slide/bg1.jpg","img/default/slide/bg2.jpg","img/default/slide/bg3.jpg"]
```

**what i tried?**

```
var slider_container = [];

    <?php foreach($sliders as $slide): ?>
      slider_container[] = "img/sliders/<?php echo $slide['Homeslider']['display_photo'] ?>";
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    console.log(slider_container);
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Javascript **does not support** such syntax

Comment: There is no `index/key` ??

Comment: @u_mulder which is the best way to go about it?

Comment: Array.push, but why not just JSON encode it

Comment: @MageshKumaar i dont need one. i need to pass it to a slider in the format ["img/default/slide/bg1.jpg","img/default/slide/bg2.jpg","img/default/slide/bg3.jpg"]

Comment: Try : slider_container = new Array(); slider_container.push(variable);

Comment: And still this can be done via json.

Comment: @adeneo can u explain please.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support PHP's `array[] = ...` syntax, but you don't need it here, either.

Two options:

#### Create an array with just what you want in PHP, then `json_encode`:

```
var slider_container =
<?php
$images = [];
foreach($sliders as $slide) {
    $images[] = $slide['Homeslider']['display_photo'];
}
echo json_encode($images);
?>;
```

*(My PHP-fu is weak, apologies for errors in the PHP of that.)*

#### Do it with your loop, but correctly (but there's a snag):

```
var slider_container = [
    <?php foreach($sliders as $slide): ?>
      "img/sliders/<?php echo $slide['Homeslider']['display_photo'] ?>",
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ""
];
--slider_container.length;
console.log(slider_container);
```

Note that game I had to play there with the commas, putting in an extra entry at the end just to remove it afterward. *Most* modern browsers would just ignore the trailing comma, but there are still a couple kicking around that would leave an `undefined` entry at the end, so for max compat you might consider this. (More on the trailing comma in [this post on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/literal-improvement.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like to mix js and php, it gets ugly and editors don't like (indententation and so on).

I'd do something like:

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $val) {
        $filteredArr[] = "img/sliders/".$val['Homeslider']['display_photo'];
    }
?>

<span id="arrayEl" style="display:none"><?=json_encode($filteredArr);?></span>
<script>
    var slider_container = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("arrayEl").innerText);
</script>
```